# Removing few rows from the dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python

There are some set of products which cannot be assigned together (e.g. product “5649565” and “5649646” cannot be given together to any customer). You can get this list in the Exclusion table:

| product1 | product2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5649646 | 5649565 |
| 5649585 | 5649910 |
| 5649585 | 5649921 |
| 5649607 | 5649931 |
| 5649607 | 5649929 |

df_customers:

| customers | product | relevancy_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A10001 | 5649646 | 0.646916 |
| A10001 | 5649565 | 0.608653 |
| A10001 | 5649585 | 0.587336 |
| A10001 | 5649910 | 0.581182 |
| A10001 | 5650462 | 0.575269 |
| A10787 | 5650544 | 0.008170 |
| A10787 | 5649815 | 0.003877 |
| A10787 | 5649925 | 0.002392 |

i.e customer A10001 should get only one of the products, not both of products at same index for example customer A10001 should either get 5649646 or 5649565 but can't get both of them . But we can see in the df_customers table that he have got both the product so I have to remove the row having product 5649565 with the A10001 customer. How can I solve this with python.

Comment: Do you imply that only the product with the highest ``relevancy_score`` should stay in the table for any given customer?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which product should be given a preference. The one with the highest `relevancy_score` or product 1 over product 2?

Here is a solution to prefer higher `relevancy_score`, for example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customers': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'product': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
    'relevancy_score': [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.95, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4],
})

new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        group[group['relevancy_score'] == group['relevancy_score'].max()]
        for _, group in df.groupby('customers')
    ]
)
print(new_df)
```

Output

```
   customers product  relevancy_score
1          1       b             0.90
3          2       c             0.95
6          3       a             0.80
```

Comment: Sorry but in your above example i want that like if a customer 1 have products 'a' and 'b' together. I have another dataframe that says  'a' and 'b' should not be given to the same customer i.e we have to remove the row where customer 1 have given 'b' product